# Python convert unicode minus sign to float

Tags: python, unicode

I have a string parsed from html: u'\u2212$9.02', (-$9.02)

Simply do an float() convert doesn't work. 'decimal' codec can't encode character u'\u2212' in position 0: invalid decimal Unicode string.

Maybe try to detect '\u2212' in the string? But then how to do that?

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```
s = u'\u2212$9.02'
float(s.replace(u'\u2212', '-').replace('$', ''))
```

Note that the dollar sign also causes a problem.

Answer (score 2):

For currencies, I prefer to the use the `Decimal` module; instead of dealing with floats:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> i = Decimal(s.replace(u'\u2212','-').replace('$',''))
>>> i
Decimal('-9.02')
```

You might be wondering why? You can read up on the approximations of floats in computers, but in practical terms, here is an example where Decimal makes more sense:

```
>>> 1.1 + 2.2
3.3000000000000003
>>> Decimal('1.1') + Decimal('2.2')
Decimal('3.3')
>>> 1.30 + 1.20
2.5
>>> Decimal('1.30') + Decimal('1.20')
Decimal('2.50')
```

The above examples and other uses for Decimal module taken from the [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re

def currency_to_cents(s):
    m = re.match(r"([−+]?)\$(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?", s)

    if m is None:
        raise ValueError("{!r} is not correctly-formatted currency".format(s))

    sign, dollars, cents = m.groups()
    amount = int(dollars) * 100

    if cents:
        amount += int(cents)

    if sign == "−":
        amount = -amount

    return amount
```

It’s usually better to manage currency as cents (or smaller, if necessary) because of floating-point errors.